# SQL Join Using mid()

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I get this to work?
I have multiple tables and in DATA.REQ.R_NUM there is one number and I want to join that on DATA.REQ_NUM.DUAL_VALUE which has 2 numbers with a comma to seperate the 2 vallues.

Or should i do this tottally different?
Thanks in advance.

```
INNER JOIN DATA.REQ_NUM
ON DATA.REQ.R_NUM     = MID(DATA.REQ_NUM.DUAL_VALUE,0,8)
```

**Data inside DATA.REQ.R_NUM**

1. 4567891
2. 4567892
3. 4567893

**Data inside DATA.REQ_NUM.DUAL_VALUE**

1. 53636835, 4567891
2. 72242441, 4567892
3. 23442344, 4567893

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the numbers are the same length:

```
ON DATA.REQ.R_NUM  = substr(DATA.REQ_NUM.DUAL_VALUE, 1, 8)
```

Otherwise, you can do:

```
ON ','||DATA.REQ_NUM.DUAL_VALUE||',' like '%,'||DATA.REQ.R_NUM||',%'
```

By the way, you should have a second field for the second value.  It would improve the performance of these types of queries.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this asap. I'm afraid I cannot change the database or even the way the data is entered. I'm only allowed to query.